# What do you call a monoid generated from a semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a semigroup $G$ and I want to construct a monoid $M$ that has every element in $G$ plus an identity.  I want to call this  the free monoid generated from $G$, but that means something completely different.  Is there a standard name for this construction?

Comment: "Unitisation of $G$", perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nLab calls this the [unitalization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitalization).

Answer (score 1):

Usually from a semigroup $S$ you construct a monoid $S^1$ by adding an unity to $S.$ That is $S^1= S\cup {1},$ where the multiplication in $S^1$ is given by $x\cdot y=xy$ for $x,y\in S$ and $x\cdot 1=1\cdot x=x$ for all $x\in S.$

Comment: In words, what would you call $S^1$ though?  I have a programming library for working with algebraic structures and I'm trying to figure out what to call this function.

Comment: I do not know a name for this $S^1.$ I think there is no standard name.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help